# Syncing configurations in predefined sequence

Tags: unicorn

I have Helix-Habitat based solutions which contains lots of Foundation and Feature projects. I want to set a sequence / order of modules to perform Unicorn sync.

Can anybody guide me here?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

> dependencies="Foundation.Serialization,Foundation.Indexing"

notation in your Unicorn config files.

So if you need module **Feature.Navigation** to be dependent on **Foundation.Serialization,Foundation.Indexing** modules you would make it like this

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
    <unicorn>
    <configurations>
        <configuration name="Feature.Navigation" description="Feature Navigation" dependencies="Foundation.Serialization,Foundation.Indexing" patch:after="configuration[@name='Foundation.Serialization']">
        <targetDataStore physicalRootPath="$(sourceFolder)\feature\navigation\serialization" type="Rainbow.Storage.SerializationFileSystemDataStore, Rainbow" useDataCache="false" singleInstance="true" />
        <predicate type="Unicorn.Predicates.SerializationPresetPredicate, Unicorn" singleInstance="true">
            <include name="Feature.Navigation.Templates" database="master" path="/sitecore/templates/Feature/Navigation" />
            <include name="Feature.Navigation.Renderings" database="master" path="/sitecore/layout/renderings/Feature/Navigation" />
        </predicate>
        <roleDataStore type="Unicorn.Roles.Data.ReverseHierarchyRoleDataStore, Unicorn.Roles" physicalRootPath="$(sourceFolder)\feature\navigation\roles" singleInstance="true"/>
        <rolePredicate type="Unicorn.Roles.RolePredicates.ConfigurationRolePredicate, Unicorn.Roles" singleInstance="true">
            <include domain="modules" pattern="^Feature Navigation .*$" />
        </rolePredicate>
        </configuration>
    </configurations>
    </unicorn>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Unicorn will automatically determine order of projects / modules based on this configuration therefore Foundation.Serialization and Foundation.Indexing modules will be synced first and then Feature.Navigation.

You can also use wildcards and set dependencies this way:

> dependencies="Foundation.*"

which will automatically push current module to be synced after all Foundation one.

You can see more examples on how to set dependencies in Unicorn in this [example config file in Unicorn GitHub](https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn/blob/master/src/Unicorn/Standard%20Config%20Files/Unicorn.Configs.Dependency.config.example).

Sample configuration for this example / answer was taken from [Helix documentation](http://helix.sitecore.net/principles/sitecore-items/development.html).